# Making a command key for an option that already exists

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, automator, shortcut

Introduction: Hello, my formatting may look weird but I'm hoping it will be more concise for you and easier to follow, I have ADHD so my writing sometimes goes from one thing to another without any transition. So I've attempted to avoid that in this question by leaving my outline in place for you. Thank you in advance for your time. I will truly appreciate it.

Problem Explanation:
I'm trying to find out how to create a command key for an option that already exists on my mac. The menu under "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts" doesn't work because this command isn't one of it's options. The command I would like to create a shortcut to is "Right click (on text) > Transformations > Make Lower/Upper Case." I seem to be using this all the time and there is apparently not a keyboard shortcut option built into the mac for this.

Explicitly Stated Question:
How do I get the command which I currently access through "Right click (on text) > Transformations > Make Lower/Upper Case" to have it's own keyboard shortcut?

Other information (about me to help your answer help me): I'm not experienced in programing whatsoever. I would like to be but my few attempts at it have been fails. So I would like to avoid Applescript as much as possible, If you have to suggest Applescript in order to answer my question please be as explanatory as possible. Meaning, help me learn how to create the code myself don't just tell me the code to put in, where to look up the commands, what my code should look like, etc.

Comment: "System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts" Works for me, because Upper/Lower case is in the menu as well: "Edit > Transformations > Make Upper Case" & ""Edit > Transformations > Make Lower Case"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking in the right direction… though you cannot actually do this easily for a right click item - so long as there is a menu item in the same app, it's simple.

I've only quickly tested this on Safari & TextEdit - whichever app you use must already have those 2 command options somewhere in their menu structure.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Select All Applications, then click the + button.

So long as you add the full, correct menu title [& that item exists in the app you are going to be using], the shortcut you ask it to use in the 3rd line will *always* find it. You don't need to enter any kind of menu hierarchy at all.

[image]

Comment: This also works for me. 

P.S. Are You a pianist? ;)

Comment: I've been known to tickle the ivories in my time, yeah :)