# System-wide plaintext paste command override

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

<kbd>Command-Option-Shift-V</kbd> is the command used for plaintext paste (after a copy or cut operation). However, for my purpose, I almost never require the source formatting.

Is there a way to switch this behaviour, i.e., use <kbd>Command-V</kbd> for plaintext paste and <kbd>Command-Option-Shift-V</kbd> for formatted paste?

Comment: Similar to this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/185942/85275 - it will only work in apps that have those as dedicated menu items. It's also going to mess up paste in such as Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**System Settings** (Preferences as was) has options to set key commands per-app, or globally, in the **Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts** panel.

**Paste and Match Style** is the name of the command you want: it doesn't remove formatting, but just matches the style to the current environment.

Note that if you switch the shortcuts globally, apps that don't have a **Paste and Match Style** won't work, e.g. Paste in Finder.

Your alternative is to trigger some script or "Shortcut" (e.g. the successor to Automator) that strips formatting in the pasteboard before you paste.